# Nginx regex pcre_compile() failed

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Can someone explain why the following condition is failing? Seems like the last `)` is cut off.

```
    location / {
        if ($request_uri !~ "(abc|def)" {
            return 404;
        }
    ...
```

fails with:

```
2021/10/07 13:29:50 [emerg] 183#183: pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "(abc|def" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/local.dev.conf:26
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "(abc|def" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conf.d/local.dev.conf:26
```

Funny enough, this seems to be "valid".

```
        if ($request_uri !~ "(abc|def))" {
            return 404;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `)` of the `if (`.

```
if ($request_uri !~ "(abc|def)") {
    return 404;
}
```